# Querying a Postgres View

Tags: postgresql, heroku, view

I created a view using the new [Postgres Studio](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pgstudio) from Heroku. I'm unable to query the view in my code. I can list the view using `\dv` as shown below but if I attempt a `select * from x` I get a `relation "x" does not exist` error. So how do I create and query views from Heroku?

```
psql> \dv
                  List of relations
 Schema |        Name        | Type |     Owner      
--------+--------------------+------+----------------
 public | x  | view | me
 public | pg_stat_statements | view | me
```

Comment: try `select * from "X"`

Comment: Thanks, That worked! Why don't you write it as an answer and I can mark it correct and close it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostgreSQL is **case-sensitive**.

So `x` and `X` are different

You should use  `select * from "X"`

Comment: Using the `"` actually made the difference which is weird because  `select * from pg_stat_statements` works without quotes

Comment: It is not weird. If the table/view/whatever name is not in quotes, it's used as lowercase. Quotes will force Pgsql to use the name as is, with uppercase letters and all. pg_stat_statements is lowercase so no need for quotes.